# Importing a module sets the file's docstring to None

Tags: python

```
"""
This here is a docstring
"""

print(f'Doc=[{__doc__}]')
```

prints

```
Doc=[
This here is a docstring
]
```

whereas

```
import sys

"""
This here is a docstring
"""

print(f'Doc=[{__doc__}]')
```

prints

```
Doc=[None]
```

What gives? The module imported doesn't have to be `sys`, the same happens with `re` and `argparse`.

```
$ python -V
Python 3.10.12
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answer; per [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#imports):

> Imports are always put at the top of the file, just ***after** any module comments and **docstrings***, and before module globals and constants.

Answer (score 1):

Per [PEP 257](https://peps.python.org/pep-0257/):

> A docstring is a string literal that occurs as the first statement in a module, function, class, or method definition. Such a docstring becomes the `__doc__` special attribute of that object.

In other words, docstrings should be at the top before anything else, including imports.

```py
"""
This here is a docstring
"""

import sys

print(f"Doc=[{__doc__}]")
```

Out

```
Doc=[
This here is a docstring
]
```

A more detailed explanation for why `__doc__` isn't assigned:

> String literals occurring elsewhere in Python code may also act as documentation. They are not recognized by the Python bytecode compiler and are not accessible as runtime object attributes (i.e. not assigned to `__doc__`), but two types of extra docstrings may be extracted by software tools:
>
> 1. String literals occurring immediately after a simple assignment at the top level of a module, class, or `__init__` method are called “attribute docstrings”.
>
> 2. String literals occurring immediately after another docstring are called “additional docstrings”.